# Covering android ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

While I was working on my project I found that the image couldn't cover the whole space of ImageView completely! this is the first time that i have got a problem like this.

**Here is my code** :

```
int ImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("test1", "drawable", getPackageName());
Photo=new LinearLayout(this);
lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Width/2,Width/2);
Photo.setLayoutParams(lp);
Photo.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
Photo.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mainGreen));
Img = new ImageView(this);
lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
Img.setLayoutParams(lp);
Img.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
Img.setImageResource(ImgId);
Photo.addView(Img);
```

I have used this piece of code many times before. The image covered the ImageView's space but now its not working well! 
What is the problem? How can I cover ImageView completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Img.setBackground(ImgId);
 //Img.setImageResource(ImgId);
```

or

```
Img.setBackground(ImgId);
Img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);  
Img.setImageResource(ImgId);
```

Comment: i added only the second line and it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just add [`ScaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) to the `ImageView` to specify the behavior

```
Img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Comment: some parts of image are being cut !

Comment: Yeah that happens if your image has different aspect to the `ImageView`. There are other scale types, just find which one you need.